# Finding the 4 consecutive numbers of the same value - horizontally

Tags: java, matrix

I have to find how many horizon lines have 4 consecutive number of the same value in the matrix (8x7). If I'm right, there are 2 horizontal lines.

2  1  1  6  1  0  0

2  1  1  7  6  0  1

1  1  7  1  6  1  1

9  7  6  0  1  1  6

7  9  1  1  6  9  0

7  5  9  2  2  2  0

7  5  **9  9  9  9**  0

7  **1  1  1  1**  0  0

But when I run it:

**# of Horizontal Lines: 3**

Would anybody know how to fix this problem?

Problem changed after a comment helped with my 1st problem.

```
public class Q5_Numbers{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int[][] matrix = {
            {2, 1, 1, 6, 1, 0, 0},
            {2, 1, 1, 7, 6, 0, 1},
            {1, 1, 7, 1, 6, 1, 1},
            {9, 7, 6, 0, 1, 1, 6},
            {7, 9, 1, 1, 6, 9, 0},
            {7, 5, 9, 2, 2, 2, 0},
            {7, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0},
            {7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}
        }; 

        // # of Horizontal Lines = 2 
        System.out.printf("# of Horizontal lines: %d\n", findHorizontal(matrix));
    }

    public static int findHorizontal(int[][] values){
        int countH = 0;
        int found = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){ 
            int current = values[i][0];
            for(int j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++){
                if(values[i][j] == current){
                    found++;
                    if(found == 4){
                        countH++;
                        found = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return countH;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to reset `found` to 0, sometimes.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Ah thank you. But now I found another problem because for some reason the # is 3 instead of 2

Comment: Also notice that those 4 consecutive values may not be the same value that starts each line, so `int current = values[i][0];` seems a bit off. You're counting how many elements are the same as the first, not how many consecutive elements there are

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca How should I go about to fix that?

Comment: Your `current` value must not stop at the beginning of your row , as @FedericoklezCulloca has already said. Also in the inner loop you need an else block that handles the case `values[i][j] != current`. You now get the three because your 3 line contains 5 identical numbers (even if they are not in a row you still count them as consecutive ), so the counter countH is increased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the code to reset `found` and keep track of previous element in `current`

like this:

```
 public static int findHorizontal(int[][] values) {
    int countH = 0, found = 0, current;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      current = values[i][0];
      found = 0;
      for (int j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
        if (values[i][j] == current) {
          if (++found == 4) {
            countH++;
            break;
          }
        }
        current = values[i][j];
      }
    }
    return countH;
  }
```

, main

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] matrix = { { 2, 1, 1, 6, 1, 0, 0 }, { 2, 1, 1, 7, 6, 0, 1 }, { 1, 1, 7, 1, 6, 1, 1 },
        { 9, 7, 6, 0, 1, 1, 6 }, { 7, 9, 1, 1, 6, 9, 0 }, { 7, 5, 9, 2, 2, 2, 0 }, { 7, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0 },
        { 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 } };

    System.out.printf("# of Horizontal lines: %d\n", findHorizontal(matrix));
  }
```

, output

```
# of Horizontal lines: 2
```

Comment: Thank you. This fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to instantiate the `current` variable each time you visit an element in a row, because when you fix `current` to first element in the row you miss the chance of counting the consecutive 4 when such a row doesn't begin with first element in the row.

For example in the row `7, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0` if you fix `current` to `7`, you miss this row. Also you need to instantiate `found` for every such `current`.

With that, the code will be:

```
    public static int findHorizontal(int[][] values){
        int countH = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){ 
            for(int j = 0; j < values[i].length; ){
                int current = values[i][j];
                int k = j;
                int found = 0;
                while ( j < values[i].length 
                        && values[i][j] == current  
                        && found < 4 ) {
                    found++;
                    j++;
                }
                if ( found == 4 ) {
                    countH++;
                    break;
                }
                if ( j == k ) j++;
            }
        }
        return countH;
    }
```

Comment: This works, but that inner `while` loop introduces an unneeded complexity to the algorithm. sc0der's solution seems simpler. Have an upvote anyway.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca while loop doesn't increase time complexity you didn't mean by that right? Because j is updated in the while loop. But to know consecutive 4 you need to stop somewhere and continue to look and it is easy enough to read. Most importantly it doesn't increase time.

Comment: No, I didn't mean time complexity. I think a better expression would have been "mental burden". But, as I said, I find sc0oder's solution easier to reason about. But maybe that's just me.

Comment: Agreed. It is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

1) Comparing items against the first item in the line is wrong. A line such as this will not be a match when it should be

```
2 1 1 1 1
```

2) Resetting `found` only on reaching 4 items is wrong, since any line without 1, 2, or 3 matches will carry over to the next line's count.

```
1 1 1 2
// found = 3
1 2 3 4
```

3) You are doing nothing to ensure the values are consecutive. You are just counting the occurrences on the line. This will be a match when it should not be

```
1 1 2 1 1
```

I suggest you change your dataset to be smaller so it is easier for you to debug. Try plugging in the examples I gave above, and observing whether the output is 1 or 0.

For example

```
int[][] matrix = {
    {1, 1, 2, 1, 1}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer

```
//This'd be a lot sweeter with foldRight
(int) Arrays.stream(values).filter(arr -> {
      int prev = arr[0], found = 0;
      for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i ++) {
        int x = arr[i];
        if (prev == x) {
          if (++found == 3) return true;
        } else {
          found = 0;
          prev = x;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

package com.vish.array;

public class Matrix
{

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    int[][] matrix = {
            {2, 1, 1, 6, 1, 0, 0},
            {2, 1, 1, 7, 6, 0, 1},
            {1, 1, 7, 1, 6, 1, 1},
            {9, 7, 6, 0, 1, 1, 6},
            {7, 9, 1, 1, 6, 9, 0},
            {7, 5, 9, 2, 2, 2, 0},
            {7, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0},
            {7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}
    };

    // # of Horizontal Lines = 2
    System.out.printf("# of Horizontal lines: %d\n", findHorizontal(matrix));
}

public static int findHorizontal(int[][] values)
{
    int countH = 0;
    int found = 0;
    int no_of_rows = values.length;
    int no_of_cols = 0;

    for(int rownum = 0; rownum < no_of_rows; rownum++)
    {
        no_of_cols = values[rownum].length;
        for ( int k= 0;k < no_of_cols-2 ;k++)
        {
            int current = values[rownum][k];
            found = 0;
            for (int columnno = k + 1; columnno < no_of_cols ; columnno ++)
            {
                if (values[rownum][columnno] == current)
                {
                   found++;
                    if (found == 3)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Row no is " + rownum + "," + columnno);
                        System.out.println("Element is " + current);
                        countH++;
                        found = 0;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    found = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return countH;
}
```

}